# Check if controller has a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a dropdown I have fetched all controller classes with all their actions in another dropdown dynamically which are used for certain operations. There are some controllers that don't have any models like 'DashboardsController' don't have `Dashboard` model. It is just used to display dashboards.

So, basically I need to filter out controllers without models. I need a method to which I pass the controller class and returns me `true/false`.

```
def has_model?(controller_klass)
 # TODO
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this, if you pass in the name of the controller as a string. This solution assumes that your models are using `ActiveRecord` prior to rails 5 where `ApplicationRecord` was used to define models; in that case just switch `ActiveRecord::Base` with `ApplicationRecord`. Also if you have models that are plain old ruby objects (POROs), then this wont work for them.

```
def has_model?(controller_klass)
  begin
    class_string = controller_klass.to_s.gsub('Controller', '').singularize
    class_instance = class_string.constantize.new
    return class_instance.class.ancestors.include? ActiveRecord::Base 
  rescue NameError => e
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, this one's better.

Comment: That is actually really encouraging to my focus on development (the comment) thanks.

Comment: BTW I'm using Rails 4

Comment: It probably doesn't. controller_klass is plural, model_klass is singular. ;)

Comment: yes you are right, I will update. And borrow `.singularize`

Comment: Did you test it? I'm pretty sure it returns false every time.

Comment: Yea that line that was calling `constantize` was not assigning that new constant to the `class_instance` variable. fixed

Comment: Finally, ApplicationRecord is a subclass of ActiveRecord::Base. You probably don't need to change anything for Rails 5. Relying on exceptions for common cases isn't recommended, though.

Comment: Yea I agree that relaying on exceptions for common cases isn't recommended, but I don't know that is what is going on here. In the event that this method is used on a out of scope class or a miss spelled class it will produce and error when it is constantized, those two examples are not common intended use cases. Also those exceptions don't negate the falsehood of the intended predicate.

Comment: It will raise an exception for the provided example : DashboardsController

Comment: I see what you mean, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

This method doesn't rely on exceptions, and works with input as Class or String. It should work for any Rails version :

```
def has_model?(controller_klass)
  all_models = ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.map(&:to_s)
  model_klass_string = controller_klass.to_s.sub(/Controller$/,'').singularize
  all_models.include?(model_klass_string)
end
```

Note : you need to set

```
config.eager_load = true
```

in

> config/environments/development.rb

If you have non ActiveRecord models, you can ignore the previous note and use :

```
all_models = Dir[File.join(Rails.root,"app/models", "**","*.rb")].map{|f| File.basename(f,'.rb').camelize}
```